# simulink model where series capacitor is used as facts device

Tags: power-electronics, simulation, matlab, simulink

I have no clue what is going on in the following simulink model. I don't know how to give the input, check which scope for the output, nothing. I have no clue where the series capacitor is being used as an FACTS device or if it hasn't even been implemented in the current model. Please help me understand how to make it work and what I'm supposed to do. My project is implementation of TCSC for Power Flow Enhancement.The research paper I'm referring to says this about the model:"In a power system there are multiple transmission
lines of different lengths and parameters which
interconnect generators and loads. Figure 5 is a single
line diagram of a three bus power system. It consists
of two generators, three transmission lines and a
single load. The hardware prototype development
was based on this three bus power system. The three
transmission lines are labeled A, B and C. Generator
one is the slack bus generator which is simply a
voltage source. The complex voltages applied at the
slack bus are determined by the reference angle and
the specified voltage magnitude of that generator
with equation
V=VRe+jVIm

Generator 2 is a generator based on the swing
equation model. The gives MATLAB /
SIMULINK model for the corresponding IEEE 3 bus system. MATLAB/SIMULINK model is used for
transmission line modeling on IEEE 3 BUS system.
Here three  section transmission lines are
interconnected. Two generating source are connected
to the bus 1 and bus 2 and load is connected to the
bus three. Transmission line parameter plays an
important role in the power flow controlling.By varying line impedance we can control the power
flow through the transmission very effectively. In
addition to these FACTS devices like TCSC are also
used for power flow control. Here we used series
capacitor as a FACTS device and try to find what
changes occur on the load side and also in the
current.
VI. RESULT
Power flows effectively controlled of three bus
system with actual implementation of FACT devices
and find the load variation with the changing in
transmission line parameter.
Without TCSC With TCSC
POWER 23.40MW     24.25MW
[image]